# Mac download speed keeps decreasing

Tags: macos, networking, wireless-networking, download, speed

I have a Mac that is getting extremely low connection speed from my WiFi. The other 3 computers in this house have a fast connection. However, on this Mac, once I connect to WiFi it's fast, but as time goes on the speed decreases dramatically.

I thought it was the browser or something (Safari) so I downloaded Firefox, but I have watched the download speed decrease consistently as time goes by and right now it's at 8kb/sec instead of the 60-200 range it started at. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On what site are you downloading ?

Is your computer far from the router ?

Are all the computers trying to download at the same time or are any bittorrent client running ?

What do you see when you <kbd>alt</kbd>-click on the airport icon next to the clock (throughput, RSSI) ?

Did this happen with the other two computers ?

Comment: Also bring up Activity Monitor to see what you've got running.